# Converting a string array to a large number array

Tags: java, arrays, string, int, largenumber

So, in Java I have a large number in the command argument, let's say 12345678910, and I cannot use bigInteger, and I already did:

```
String[] g = args[1].split("");
```

So, my string is put in a string array. But, I cannot use:

```
int[] ginormintOne = new int[g.length];
   for(int n = 0; n < g.length; n++) {
      ginormintOne[n] = Integer.parseInt(g[n]);
   }
```

It gives me this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Ginormint.main(Ginormint.java:67)
```

I think my numbers are too large for int. Any idea on how to convert it to a large number array?

Comment: Any reason not to use `java.lang.Long` ?  it is 64-bit signed

Comment: Let's assume that somebody puts in an arbitrarily large number, taking up more than 64 bits. How would I do it then?

Comment: BigDecimal * 10^x (scientific notation)

Comment: You can't do it without `BigInteger` or any other class with the same functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first element of the array from `args[1].split("")` is an empty string that to my opinion causes the exception `java.lang.NumberFormatException` since it cannot be converted to an `Integer`

Answer (score 5):

You are splitting on an empty string. For example,

```
"123 456".split("")
```

results in this array:

```
["" "1" "2" "3" " " "4" "5" "6"]
```

This is where your exception comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Long.parseLong` instead of `Integer.parseInt` and a `long[]` instead of `Long.parseLong`.

But that said, the `NumberFormatException` indicates the failure is because you're passing it an empty string.  Are you sure you're splitting the string correctly, or that splitting is even necessary?  The `args` array in `main` is already split on spaces, assuming that's where `args` is coming from.